# Error on can't resolve R.layout.list_item_forecast and R.id.list_item_forecast_textview

Tags: java, android

I'm taking the udacity course and I am so new to Android so i know i'm missing something very basic.

I have two symbol variables that are giving me errors saying they cant be resolved  R.layout.list_item_forecast and R.id.list_item_forecast_textview

Any help is appreciated.

```js
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            String[] data = {
                    "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                    "Tomorrow - Foggy 70/40",
                    "Weds - Cloudy 72/62",
                    "Thurs - Snow 34 Possible!!",
                    "Fri - Milk Bread TP",
                    "Sat - Cloudy 72/62",
                    "Sun - Cloudy 72/62",
            };
            List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
            char shape;

            mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                            R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                            weekForecast);

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

layout.list_item_forecast is the layout file defining each row of text view in your case it will only contain text view.
And `R.id.list_item_forecast_textview` is the id of text view contained in layout file `R.layout.list_item_forecast`.
Share your layout file to get further help :)